# Sync two movies, frame-accurate?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, sync

Given video recordings made on two (or more) cameras such as gopros or keychain cameras, and given a "clapperboard" event in each recording, what is a simple way to trim each recording to start with the synchronizing event?

(The recordings are short enough to not worry about sync drifting apart afterwards.)

This is probably a duplicate of another question, but which question?
Overlaying hh:mm:ss:ff on a player?

Comment: If your getting into doing that, you need to be looking at the various multitrack editing softwares that exist and have been around for 15+ years. They make tasks like this , especially with proper clapboard easy.  Syncing video portions by viewing them both at the same time, or syncing audio by the visable waveforms.  I only mention it because it sounds like the wrong software is getting in the way of your creative endeavors.

Comment: Fair enough.  Can you recommend any in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_editing_software that aren't a sledgehammer for this kind of simple work?  I'm more of a software designer than a video producer.

Comment: edius is my choice, sony vegas was more intuitive also. they are all way more complex than nessisary for 80% of jobs, if you just ignore everything :-) and drop some videos in and sync and edit them, you can survive, the complexity can be overlooked.  They are now (because of speedy processing) putting in ability to live switch between 2 video sources too, making a reassemble of a couple of cams (or even 4) quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract each audio track.  In an audio editor such as Audacity, measure the offset from the start of each recording to the clapperboard event (a loud hand-clap, for instance).

Comment: You answered your own question in under a minute?

Comment: In under a second, once it hit me that audio sync is far easier than video sync!